New figures on the Chess-Python-Board
I want to add to my Python Chess Endgame Engine 3 new figures:Amazon, Bob and Cyryl.Amazon moves like knight and bishop,Bob as a  rook and knight
and Cyryl as Queen and Knight. I have code like this.
But besides that I'm unable to compute optimal moves from start_fen, which is more difficult than this: I'm even unable to print an ASCII board
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . A .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
k . K . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .

It keeps printing for start_fen = "8/6A1/8/8/8/k1K5/8/8 w - - 0 1"
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . B .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
k . K . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .

I would like to have the code fixed so that it doesn't print 0 in here
Number of positions is 406300
Number of positions at checkmate is 216
Evaluation at level 1
Found `0` positions at level 1
0h 3m 37s / 0h 1m 44s
Found 0 positions all
Positions with to_end == 17:
*****
Pozice s to_end == -20:
Evaluation of intial position is 0

On the other hand, this code works 100% fine, though it takes 25 minutes for 3 pieces.

I don't speak Czech. Please update with English labels.

Please focus on one question only (the ASCII output or the 0 output), and provide the results of your debugging session.

@trincot Good that you have recognized that it was in Czech language, I'm pleased. Could you have a look at my question now, mainly at 0 positions but also at wanted A and not wanted B ? The questions are entangled so I've posted them as one Q. I've added the code for standard figures QqKkPpBbNnRr which works fully correct. Now I want to make it work also for A=knight+bishop

What would you like to print it instead of 0?

@mkrieger1 The number of half-moves (plies) to checkmate. Try this for standard figures (unlike for non-standard Amazonka Bob and Cyryl) and see what it does. It prints a fully optimal path from start_fen to a checkmate. It prints something like 995 if there are 5 moves plies to a checkmate. So it should print 995==1000-5. Now I want to make the code owrk for ABC as well.

So in your code you need to change it to print that number instead of 0.

@mkrieger1 Yes the code is incorrect and hence it prints 0. I cannot determine where is the bug. The code is supposed to be  a fully optimal procedure for checkmating player to approach checkmate in as few plies as possible and the checkmated player to delay it.

See: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

@mkrieger1 I've asked ChatGPT4o but it keeps giving a wrong answer keeping printing B instead of A. This change should be the first step.
